# Converting sub-gaussian norm to sub-gaussianity and vice versa

Tags: probability, probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

So suppose I have a random variable $X$ which is $\sigma$-sub-gaussian, i.e. $\log \mathbb Ee^{\lambda X} \leq \lambda^2 \sigma^2/2$. We also know such a r.v. has a norm associated with it called the sub-gaussian norm defined as:

$$
   \|X\|_{\psi_2} = \inf\left\{t>0:\mathbb{E}\exp\left( \frac{X^2}{t^2}\right)\le2\right\}.
$$

My question is, how do we convert between $\sigma \Longleftrightarrow
\|X\|_{\psi_2}$ without the use of universal constants? I want to move back and forth between these terms without losing any information.

Comment: It is not quite possible to move back and forth without using constants. To see this, confer Prop. 2.5.2 in Vershynin's "High-Dimensional Probability" (and particularly the proof, it shows how the constants change between steps). However, I would be interested in knowing if these constants can be made explicit, and I think this would help your cause as well.